# Pack layout isn't binding to updated dataset properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I have a pack layout chart that displays the firms and users for a web application.  The chart has separate dataset symbolizing different periods of time.

Example -

1. All users
2. Only users logged in within the last week
3. Only users logged in within the last 30 days
4. ...

My dataset is structured like this-

```
{
  all: {
    name: "Web App",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Firm 1",
        size: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Cathy",
            size: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Paula",
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 2",
        size: 1,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sean",
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 3",
        size: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Jennifer",
            size: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Amy",
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  loggedIn7Day: {
    name: "Web App",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Firm 1",
        size: 1,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Paula",
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 3",
        size: 1,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Kristin",
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to properly bind the circles after updating the dataset.

After the dataset is updated some of the parent nodes are bound to child nodes and child nodes get bound as parents.

Here is how I update the dataset and bind the circles-

```
//change property for pack based on filter
switch (filter) {
    case "1":
        root = allData.loggedIn90Day;
        break;
    case "2":
        root = allData.loggedIn30Day;
        break;
    case "3":
        root = allData.loggedIn7Day;
        break;
    default:
        root = allData.all;
}

circle = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack.nodes(root));

circle
    .enter()
    .append("circle");

circle
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - view[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - view[1]) * k + ")"; })
    .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r * k; });

circle.exit()
    .transition()
    .remove();
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple but I cannot figure it out.

Here is a JS-fiddle showing the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/t989hfp9/

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: I figured out that I needed to add unique ids to all of the nodes.  I'll post a fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the nodes didn't have an unique identifier.

I added an id property to all nodes in the dataset -

```
{
  all: {
    name: "Web App",
    id: 0,
    children: [
      {
        name: "Firm 1",
        id: 1;
        size: 2,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Cathy",
            id: 2,
            size: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Paula",
            id: 3,
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 2",
        size: 1,
        id: 4;
        children: [
          {
            name: "Sean",
            id: 5,
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 3",
        size: 2,
        id: 7,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Jennifer",
            id: 8,
            size: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Amy",
            id: 9,
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  loggedIn7Day: {
    name: "Web App",
    id: 0,
    children: [
      {
        name: "Firm 1",
        id: 1;
        size: 1,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Paula",
            id: 3,
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Firm 3",
        size: 1,
        id: 7;
        children: [
          {
            name: "Amy",
            id: 9,
            size: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you specify which property to use an the unique identifier when bind the dataset to the pack -

```
circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(pack.nodes(root), function (d) { return d.id; });
```

Here is the fixed fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ferlin_husky/wzuvob6m/